# How to decrypt signed cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am trying to decrypt a signed cookie but couldn't get any success.

The way I am using signed cookie in my session controller like this

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      if params[:remember_me]
        cookies.signed[:auth_token] = { value: user.auth_token, expires: 2.weeks.from_now }
      else
        cookies.signed[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
      end
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Email or password is invalid"
      render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    cookies.delete(:auth_token)
    redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Logged Out'
  end
end
```

Now in the application controller side, I am trying to decrypt it

```
require 'cgi'
require 'active_support'
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery


  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(auth_token: verify_and_decrypt)
  end

  def verify_and_decrypt
    config = Rails.application.config
    cookie = CGI::unescape(cookies[:auth_token])
    salt   = config.action_dispatch.authenticated_encrypted_cookie_salt
    encrypted_cookie_cipher = config.action_dispatch.encrypted_cookie_cipher || 'aes-256-gcm'
    serializer = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::NullSerializer


    key_generator = ActiveSupport::KeyGenerator.new(Rails.application.secret_key_base, iterations: 1000)
    key_len = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.key_len(encrypted_cookie_cipher)

    secret = key_generator.generate_key(salt, key_len)
    encryptor = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(secret, cipher: encrypted_cookie_cipher, serializer: serializer)

    cookie = encryptor.decrypt_and_verify(cookie)
    cookie
  end
end
```

But every time it is failing on this line cookie = encryptor.decrypt_and_verify(cookie)

```
ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
from /home/anikettiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:190:in `_decrypt'
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong

For references I checked this [link](https://gist.github.com/wildjcrt/6359713fa770d277927051fdeb30ebbf)

Comment: If you are using those cookies only from the same app where you are also creating them, you don't need to "manually" decrypt them. Just use `cookies.signed[:auth_token]` to access the raw value in your `ApplicationController` too.

Comment: why decrypt is not required here?

Comment: Because Rails does it automatically when accessing the cookie value with `cookies.signed[:auth_token]` (as compared to `cookies[:auth_token]` which will give you the raw value). Just the same as it automatically serializes, signs and encrypts the raw value when you set the cookie value in your `SessionsController`.

Comment: @HolgerJust Got it thanks for the description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just read cookie via standard rails interface: `value = cookies.signed[:auth_token]`

As for why your decryptor does not work - you generate new encryption salt, but to decrypt one should use the same salt that was used in encryption process.

Also keep in mind that signed cookies are not encrypted entirely - they only guard against tampering, but can be read by the user